# A collection of the actual smartphones

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, tikz-styles, fun, big-list

Considering the recent excellent questions that I've really enjoyed

[Welcoming 2019 Pi day: How to draw the letter π?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479395/welcoming-2019-pi-day-how-to-draw-the-letter-%cf%80/479506#479506) and [What has been your most complicated TikZ drawing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479232/what-has-been-your-most-complicated-tikz-drawing)

I have carefully observed this link [Tikz: How to create and reuse a picture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195923/tikz-how-to-create-and-reuse-a-picture?rq=1), 
where there is a beautiful image created in 2014 of a smarthpone. See image below:

[image]

Considering that we are in the year 2019, and that I also teach in an art school, I wanted to show that to create beautiful drawings, such as smartphones that they use daily, you do not necessarily need to use external programs, but just a lot of creativity and talent to create one, using mathematics.

I don't know how to draw it and I say that I'm not interested in votes or anything.

I hope you will cooperate extensively. Thank you all.

Comment: If we are to do that, wouldn't we be facing IP related issues? (But +1, for the question though `:)`).

Comment: @Raaja Hi :-) Why the problem of IP? Thank you for edit :-) I'm yet scarce :-) Have you seen if my english is correct?

Comment: if we are recreating the already existing class of mobile phones, then it will replicate their designs. I am not sure whether we can do that.

Comment: @Raaja Obviously they will have to be personalized but that resemble those that are on the market. Or each user with their own creativity can draw a custom template. If my question is not clear, could you edit it according to my comment?

Comment: I think your question is clear to me ;)

Comment: This is how my smartphone looks like: `\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[rounded corners] (0,0) rectangle (0.5,0.9);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` ;-)

Comment: @marmot Fantastic one liner so lifelike, looks like you may need to charge your phone again I can only see the lock screen / screen saver (or is it face down) sitting on your table :-)

Comment: @KJO No, this is how my phone looks like at least 98% of the time. Who cares about the remaining up to  2%?

Comment: @marmot likewise I use mine less than 0.1% but its eating up electricity in case you or anyone else ever needs to call

Comment: @KJO Wait! You are using your cell phone to make *calls*? Modern cell phones are actually not made for making calls. They are much better suited to check emails, surf in the internet and taking pictures.

Comment: @marmot You could not know, it has no camera or web access I bought it new for £1 and spend hundreds a year keeping it charged

Comment: @KJO I see. I am very excited to see a realistic tikzpicture depicting it. ;-)

Comment: @marmot here you are I found this somewhere on the site can you draw the buttons for me ? \documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone} \begin{document} \begin{tikzpicture} \fill[rounded corners] (0,0) rectangle (0.5,0.9); \end{tikzpicture} \end{document}

Comment: @KJO Sure, as long as the buttons are black.

Comment: @marmot Ok I'd better stop there before these comments are marked as a duplicate do this for me

Comment: @marmot Hi, can you transform your comment into a answer, please. Just a cell phone is great, too. I teach them during breaks that mathematics goes hand in hand with LaTeX.

Answer (score 15):

Honestly this is the most complicated Ti*k*Z picture I have ever made. The size of the phone (5 × 9) is [suggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479840/a-collection-of-the-actual-smartphones#comment1212593_479840) by [@marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/marmot).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\tiny]
\fill[yellow!50] (0,8.3) rectangle (5,8.6);
\draw[rounded corners,line width=1.5mm] (0,0) rectangle (5,9);
\fill[rounded corners] (0,8.6) |- (2.5,9) -| (5,8.6);
\fill[rounded corners] (0,0.5) |- (2.5,0) -| (5,0.5);
\draw[ultra thin,white] (4,8.85) circle (0.1);
\draw[rounded corners,very thin,white,fill=black!90] (2,0.05) rectangle (3,0.35);
\draw (2.5,4) node {\includegraphics[width=4.5cm]{lion.png}};
\begin{scope}[yshift=8.45cm]
\draw (0,0) node[right] (1) {\includegraphics[height=0.25cm]{texse.png}};
\draw (1) node[right] (2) {\includegraphics[height=0.25cm]{stackexchange.png}};
\draw (2) node[right] (3) {\includegraphics[height=0.2cm]{fb.png}};
\draw (2.5,0) node {8:42 AM};
\fill[green!50!black] (4.55,.08) rectangle (4.75,-.08);
\draw (4.8,-.08) rectangle (4.55,.08);
\fill (4.8,-.04) rectangle (4.83,.04);
\draw (4.55,0) node[left,inner sep=1pt] (i) {80\%};
\coordinate (ii) at ($(i.west)+(-0.15,-.075)$);
\fill (ii) circle (0.02cm);
\foreach \i in {1,...,4} {%
    \draw ($(ii)+(135:{0.04*\i})$) arc (135:45:{0.04*\i});
}
\end{scope}
\draw (2.5,7) node[font=\scriptsize\sffamily,inner sep=1pt] (day) {Thursday, 14 March 2019};
\draw (day.north west) node[above right,font=\Huge\sffamily,inner sep=1pt] (time) {8:42};
\draw (day.north east) node[red!50!black,above left,align=right,inner sep=1pt] {Hanoi\\15\textdegree C \scalebox{0.5}{(59\textdegree F)}\\Rainy};
\draw (time.north east) node[below right,inner sep=1pt] {AM}; 
\foreach \i in {2.3,2.5,2.7} {
    \foreach \j in {0.8,1,1.2} {
        \fill (\i,\j) circle (1.2pt);
    }
}
\fill[green,rounded corners] (0.4,0.8) rectangle (0.9,1.3);
\begin{scope}[shift={(0.65,1.05)}]
\fill[white] (135:0.2)--($(135:0.2)+(45:0.075)$)--($(135:0.1)+(45:0.075)$)--(135:0.1) to[out=-135,in=-135] (-45:0.1)--($(-45:0.1)+(45:0.075)$)--($(-45:0.2)+(45:0.075)$)--(-45:0.2) to[out=-135,in=-135] (135:0.2);
\end{scope}
\fill[blue,rounded corners] (1.3,0.8) rectangle (1.8,1.3);
\begin{scope}[shift={(1.55,1.05)}]
\fill[white,rounded corners=1pt] (-0.175,0.125) rectangle (0.175,-0.125);
\draw[blue] (-0.175,0.125)--(0,0)--(0.175,0.125);
\end{scope}
\fill[cyan,rounded corners] (3.2,0.8) rectangle (3.7,1.3);
\begin{scope}[shift={(3.45,1.05)}]
\draw[white,thick] (0,0) circle (0.15);
\draw[white,thick] (-.15,0)--(.15,0);
\foreach \i in {-150,-90,-30} {
    \draw[white,thick] (0,.15) to[out=\i,in=-\i] (0,-.15);
}
\draw[white,thick] (150:0.15)--(30:0.15);
\draw[white,thick] (-150:0.15)--(-30:0.15);
\end{scope}
\fill[gray,rounded corners] (4.1,0.8) rectangle (4.6,1.3);
\begin{scope}[shift={(4.35,1.05)}]
\draw[ultra thick,white] (0,0) circle (0.13);
\foreach \i in {0,45,...,315} {
    \coordinate (x) at (\i:0.15);
    \fill[white,rounded corners=0.1pt] ($(x)+(\i-90:0.03)$)--($(x)+(\i-90:0.03)+(\i:0.04)$)--($(x)+(\i+90:0.03)+(\i:0.04)$)--($(x)+(\i+90:0.03)$)--cycle;
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

> #### Some notes about sources I used:
>
> 1. [The TeX lion](https://ctan.org/lion) drawn by Duane Bibby.
> 2. The icons on the top left:
>
>    - TeX.SE icon: taken from a Google search. [Link to the original image](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/tex/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=eaf26b461720).
>    - Stack Exchange icon: taken from a Google search. [Link to the original image](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/se/se-icon.png?v=93426798a1d4).
>    - Facebook icon: taken from Wikipedia. [Link to the original image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cd/Facebook_logo_%28square%29.png/600px-Facebook_logo_%28square%29.png).
>
> #### About copyright
>
> According to [CTAN](https://ctan.org/lion), I'm allowed to include the TeX lion to my answer.
>
> I don't know if I am allowed to include the three icons on the top left like this. If there is any copyright issue, please comment here and I will be happy to remove the copyrighted content.

Comment: Gorgeous! I like it very much!

Comment: Your work is simply splendid. Why so great? :-( Is that a tablet? :-) Is that a tablet? :-) The suggestion of marmot is not good LOL.

Comment: @Sebastiano It is not so great: it is only 5cm x 9cm, and I think it is a bit small. You are just seeing a zoomed version of it.

Comment: JouleV @marmot hid 3.14 in his code, as I also did for my icon, but can't see where you have hidden it, ooh very very subtle just noticed the March 14 :-) P.S if my rep hits 3142 does that count :-)

Comment: @JouleV Ah I thought the beautiful code you generated was from a really big smartphone. :-) It's a pity my question isn't taken seriously.

Comment: @KJO Thank you very much for your comments. :-) They're nice.

Answer (score 6):

A sim card.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\definecolor{goldSim}{HTML}{F7E7AB}
\definecolor{graySim}{HTML}{B1B8C8}
\draw[fill=graySim]
(-1.33,2.24) -- (-2,2.94)
[rounded corners=5pt]-- (-4.75,2.94) -- (-4.75,-2.8)
[sharp corners] -- (-4.28,-2.8) arc (180:0:0.04)
-- (-1.89,-2.8) arc (180:0:0.04)
[rounded corners=5pt] -- (-1.33,-2.8)
[sharp corners]-- cycle;

\draw[fill=goldSim,rounded corners=12pt]  (-4.32,0.76) rectangle (-1.82,-2.28);

\draw (-3.05,0.76) -- (-3.05,-0.32);

\draw (-2.47,0.76) -- (-2.48,-0.29);

\draw (-1.85,-2) -- (-2.48,-2);

\draw (-3.05,-2.28) -- (-3.05,-1.2);

\draw (-3.63,-2.28) -- (-3.63,-1.24);

\draw (-2.48,-2.28) -- (-2.48,-1.28);


\draw (-4.32,-0.47) .. controls (-3.79,-0.48) 
and (-3.9,-0.42) .. (-3.75,-0.6) .. controls (-3.75,-0.7) 
and (-3.75,-0.8) .. (-3.75,-0.92) .. controls (-3.9,-1.09) 
and (-3.79,-1.04) .. (-4.32,-1.04);
\draw(-1.82,-0.37) .. controls (-1.9,-0.37) 
and (-1.94,-0.37) .. (-2,-0.37) .. controls (-2.09,-0.29) 
and (-2.11,-0.24) .. (-2.2,-0.24) .. controls (-2.25,-0.24) 
and (-2.22,-0.29) .. (-2.48,-0.29);
\begin{scope}[yshift=-1.57cm,rotate around x=180]
\draw(-1.82,-0.37) .. controls (-1.9,-0.37) 
and (-1.94,-0.37) .. (-2,-0.37) .. controls (-2.09,-0.29) 
and (-2.11,-0.24) .. (-2.2,-0.24) .. controls (-2.25,-0.24) 
and (-2.22,-0.29) .. (-2.48,-0.29);
\end{scope}
\draw (-3.64,0.76) -- (-3.64,-0.23) .. controls (-3.4,-0.23)
and (-3.5,-0.2) .. (-3.35,-0.2) .. controls (-3.2,-0.2) 
and (-3.26,-0.32) .. (-3.05,-0.32) .. controls (-2.83,-0.32) 
and (-2.9,-0.2) .. (-2.8,-0.2) .. controls (-2.7,-0.2) 
and (-2.7,-0.2) .. (-2.48,-0.29) .. controls (-2.3,-0.46) 
and (-2.35,-0.5) .. (-2.35,-0.8) .. controls (-2.35,-1.1) 
and (-2.3,-1.13) .. (-2.48,-1.28) .. controls (-2.7,-1.32) 
and (-2.7,-1.32) .. (-2.8,-1.32) .. controls (-2.9,-1.32) 
and (-2.83,-1.2) .. (-3.05,-1.2) .. controls (-3.26,-1.2) 
and (-3.2,-1.3) .. (-3.35,-1.3) .. controls (-3.62,-1.3) 
and (-3.54,-1.24) .. (-3.63,-1.24) .. controls (-3.68,-1.24) 
and (-3.74,-1.24) .. (-3.75,-0.92);

\node[yshift=4.5cm] at ($(-4.75,-2.8)!0.5!(-1.33,-2.8)$) {Ti\emph{k}Z};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Sim Card with TikZ]